# javascript access dom of <iframe> of local files(*.html) in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, same-origin-policy, local-files

it is a problem of "same origin policy" on local file, i have tried that

```
C:\somewhere some folder\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

don't work, now i am working javascript on localhost(web server) ...my situation is ridiculous,  it make the "iframe loading" and xmlhttprequest(which not work for local files) have no difference for scripting.

Does chromium just the same function as chrome except "--allow-file-access-from-files" works? if not , writing code for ie,chrome,chromium just create one more issue but solve one.

Answer (score 2):

`--allow-file-access-from-files` works for me on Chromium under Ubuntu. However, you have to close Chromium completely before this, because otherwise it will just open a tab in the existing Chromium process (which was presumably not started with that option).

Otherwise, this is just [bug 40787](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787).

Comment: thanks ,but it is too long to ranking the answer. can't find any ranking button.

Comment: @Johnny: What do you mean by "ranking"? If you mean voting on answers, click on the up or down triangles around the large number on the left side of a post to vote it up or down.